# Postgres DB query to get the count, and first and last ids by date in a single query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date, cockroachdb

I have the following db structure.

```
table
-----
 id (uuids)
date (TIMESTAMP)
```

I want to write a query in postgres (actually cockroachdb which uses the postgres engine, so postgres query should be fine).

The query should return a count of records between 2 dates , id of the record with latest date and id of the record with latest earliest date within that range.

So the query should return the following:
count, id(of the earliest record in the range),  id (of the latest record in the range)

thanks.

Comment: Are the IDs in the same order as the dates or can I find a greater ID with an older date?

Comment: Ids are uuids, so they wont be in the same order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` twice, then conditional aggregation:

```
select
    no_records,
    min(id) filter(where rn_asc = 1) first_id
    max(id) filter(where rn_desc = 1) last_id
from (
    select 
        id, 
        count(*) over() no_records
        row_number() over(order by date asc)  rn_asc, 
        row_number() over(order by date desc) rn_desc
    from mytable
    where date >= ? and date < ?
) t
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
```

The question marks represents the (inclusive) start and (exclusive) end of the date interval.

Of course, if `id`s are always increasing, simple aggregation is sufficient:

```
select count(*), min(id) first_id, max(id) last_id
from mytable
where date >= ? and date < ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Postgres doesn't support `first_value()` as an aggregation function.  One method is to use arrays:

```
select count(*),
       (array_agg(id order by date asc))[1] as first_id,
       (array_agg(id order by date desc))[1] as last_id
from t
where date >= ? and date <= ?
```

Comment: Unfortunately the actual database we use is cockroachdb, though the base engine is postgres. CockroachDb does not still allow order by in aggregate functions.

https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/23620

Comment: @user7510999 . . . Then GMB has the right answer and you should accept it.

Comment: I am still trying something out. I will accept that but I am making a few teaks.